# How valid is it to use `Result` inside `Task.Run`

Tags: c#, async-await, akka.net

In Akka.Net there is the nice design inside an actor, to start a task with `Task.Run` and pipe the result back to the actor:

```
Task.Run(() => Method(...)).PipeTo(self);
```

Note, there is no IO involved.
Inside
`Model Method(...)`
there is a little bit of pre-processing, then I have to wait on a call to a `Task<Model>` and a little bit of post-processing.
`Task<Model>` is in a third-party library, I cannot change it.
Currently I do
`var model = proxy.GetModel(..).Result` inside a `try catch`.
A possible `AggregateException` is taken into account.

Another idea is to use this with `await`.
`var model = await proxy.GetModel(..)` inside a `try catch`
and changing the signature to
`async Task<Model> Method(...)`

How should I change the call to Method in the actor?

```
Task.Run(() => Method(...).Result).PipeTo(self);
Task.Run(async () => await Method(...)).PipeTo(self);
```

Which approach is better, what is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

`Result` blocks a thread and wraps any exceptions in `AggregateException`. For these reasons, I generally prefer `await`.

In this case, you can [elide the `async`/`await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html):

```
// Same as:
// Task.Run(async () => await Method(...)).PipeTo(self);
Task.Run(() => Method(...)).PipeTo(self);
```

Comment: Without async-await keywords, I will have to use  the `Result` of the task inside `Method(..)`  because my code was somewhat simplified and the post-processing inside `Method(..)` uses the result - allthough I could refactor that.

Comment: @Gerard: No. You can have `Method` use `async`/`await` just fine, with either form of `Task.Run`.